# float.TryParse not working and the string I'm trying to parse does not have a comma nor decimal

Tags: tryparse

```
        if (!float.TryParse(tmp[0], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat, out Degrees))
        {
            this.ValidateCommandSyntaxErrorMessage = Constants.ArgumentTypeMismatch;
            return false;
        }
```

tmp[0] is "5"

I've also tried float.TryParse(tmp[0], out Degrees)

Both tries result in failure to parse

Comment: The code you posted works fine with the data you posted; my guess is one of the things you posted isn't the actual code or data. Inspect them in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. There were some special characters in the string which I only found by looping through each char in the string. Very strange problem. So to fix this I pass my text through a function to clean it up before trying to parse.

```
    public static string CleanupInput(string input)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d$");
        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            if (regex.IsMatch(c.ToString()) || c.ToString() == ".")
            {
                sb.Append(c.ToString());
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```